# MAX, GROUP BY query taking a long time across large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following pretty basic query but it takes 27 seconds to run.

Here is the execution plan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJdzqscBf

Can anyone see a way of improving it? Let me know if some sample data/table structures would be useful.

The Visit table has 1,347,957 rows and VisitMovement has 5,294,399 rows.

```
DECLARE @RecentlyLeftDate datetimeoffset(7)
SELECT @RecentlyLeftDate = dateadd(hh,-4,sysdatetimeoffset())

SELECT 
    MAX(VM.VisitMovementID) as VisitMovementID
FROM
    Visit V
INNER JOIN VisitMovement VM ON 
    V.VisitID = VM.VisitID
WHERE
    V.EndDate > @RecentlyLeftDate
GROUP BY
    V.VisitID
```

There are Indexes on the tables:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VisitMovement_VisitID] ON [dbo].[VisitMovement]
(
    [VisitID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Visit] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Visit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VisitID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Visit_EndDate] ON [dbo].[Visit]
(
    [EndDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ClientID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Comment: how many records get returned?

Comment: Are both V.VisitID and VM.VisitID indexed fields?

Comment: @juergend - between 50-100 generaly.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume - yes, have copied index statements there.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right execution plan?

Comment: Sorry @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' - not sure what happened with my copy/paste. It's correct now.

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: I see the query plan has a sort cost of 19% which can be avoided, if you can create the clustered index on temp table ,after insert.`INSERT INTO #ResultsVisitMovement

 (

  VisitMovementID

 )
`

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar for the advice there. Will remember that.

Comment: No index on Visit.VisitID?   Really odd you don't report Visit.VisitID.

Comment: @Paparazzi - Visit.VisitID is the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your query, I'm guessing VisitMovement does not have EndDate, so the join is just to use the EndDate from Visit table.  IF so, why you don't just join ID and EndDate from Visit table, rather than joining the full table ?

So, you can do this :

```
SELECT 
    MAX(VM.VisitMovementID) as VisitMovementID
FROM 
    VisitMovement VM
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT VisitID, EndDate FROM Visit WHERE EndDate > @RecentlyLeftDate) V ON V.VisitID = VM.VisitID
WHERE
    V.EndDate > @RecentlyLeftDate
GROUP BY
    V.VisitID
```

Adding `WHERE EndDate > @RecentlyLeftDate` inside the INNER JOIN will reduce the retrieved records from Visit table, so it'll retrieve only the records which fit that timeline and not retrieving the 1,347,957 records!

you may also adjust your indexes and make sure you add the identity columns under Index key columns (make sure to put the right Sort Order for each column) and in the Included columns, add the columns that are frequently used.

Alternative Method :
This is another approach that got in mind, you need to check and give it a try

```
SELECT 
    MAX(VM.VisitMovementID) as VisitMovementID
FROM 
    VisitMovement VM
WHERE 
    VisitID IN (SELECT VisitID FROM Visit WHERE EndDate > @RecentlyLeftDate)
GROUP BY 
    V.VisitID
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're correct in your thinking for the first query in that it is the only reason I do the join. Unfortunately though, your query still does a massive scan against VisitMovement and takes 20 seconds to complete. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJraBacSG

Comment: I can't do a TOP 1 as I need to retrieve all rows within the past 4 hours.

Comment: 20s is less than 27s , so you're doing some progress here ;).. it takes some patient to hit the target. However, you said you need to retrieve all rows while you're using MAX which will retrieve all rows than scan and get the max value. TOP 1 will be much faster, it'll order the results DESC then select the the TOP 1, which commonly will be the largest ID, unless your VisitMovementID is not 1,1 incremental

Comment: EDIT your index EndDate and change the sort from ASC to DESC, as you're sorting ASC and querying for the last 4 hours, you can do the same for the VisitMovementID

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the results are wrong with the TOP 1, your query returns 1 row when it should return 5.  Removing the GROUP BY V.VisitID changes this.

Comment: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Visit_EndDate] ON [dbo].[Visit]
(
 [EndDate] DESC
)
Tried this index and made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: I see now, so you're not querying for one row, I thought you only want to get one row using the max. my bad, then my first query will be also missing the group by clauses.

Comment: No worries @iSR5 - if you have any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I may have an alternative way to do it, but you have to check its performance.

Comment: @Philip check the alternative method I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for that @iSR5, appreciate that. Have tried them out and the same result. No really dramatic performance improvement. Appears as though the best thing to do is to store the latest VisitMovementID in the Visit table. Not ideal database design but would improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT MAX(VM.VisitMovementID) as VisitMovementID
FROM Visit V INNER JOIN
     VisitMovement VM 
     ON V.VisitID = VM.VisitID
WHERE V.EndDate > @RecentlyLeftDate
GROUP BY V.VisitID;
```

I find this a strange construction, because the `GROUP BY` keys are not part of the `SELECT`.

That said, the best indexes are `Visit(EndDate, VisitId)` and `VisitMovement(VisitId, VisitMovementID)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response and suggestion. Unfortunately these indexes make no difference to the execution time of the query.  Seems like the SCAN needs to be turned into a SEEK as the query has to read every row in the VisitMovement table currently?

Comment: @Philip . . . Even with the indexes, SQL Server might decide that is the most efficient execution plan.  This might be true if the `where` clause filters out few rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your query plan was good,I would avoid sort by adding Index after insert

```
INSERT INTO #ResultsVisitMovement 
( VisitMovementID )
select max(movementid)
rest of query
```

Further when i checked the query plan, i could see a lot of wait stats

```
  <Wait WaitType="RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="5" WaitCount="7527"/>
              <Wait WaitType="IO_QUEUE_LIMIT" WaitTimeMs="1250" WaitCount="76"/>
              <Wait WaitType="RESOURCE_GOVERNOR_IDLE" WaitTimeMs="18669" WaitCount="1428"/>
              <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="21248" WaitCount="945"/>
```

Memory allocation wait type is very low, so i would ignore that.You have reached IO queue limit for 1.2 seconds.

`RESOURCE_GOVERNOR_IDLE` is interesting ,i suspect you have reached certain cap and your query is forced to wait for something(IO,CPU,Memory...)

Finally SOS yeild says the total cumulative wait time is 21 seconds..

In this case i would check below

run below query to see if my azure limit(CPI,IO,RAM,log) is consistently over 90 for a  period of time.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats 
ORDER BY end_time DESC;
```

I would try to tune the resource which is high,for example, if CPU limit is consistently averaging over 90 for a period of time, then  would gather top queries causing CPU and i will try to tune them

Comment: Thanks, the query I list does indeed send the avg_cpu_percent to 98/99%.  Appears as thought the best thing to do is to store the latest VisitMovementID in the Visit table. Not ideal database design but would improve performance.